# angular2 event listening on *NgFor iterative variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**I've been exploring angular2 as a way to solve a particular data binding challenge.**

I have a javascript array of objects, essentially a database recordset, which I present in a UI as an html table.  I have various menus and inputs on each row to allow the user to modify the underlying recordset.

The overall workflow is that the user loads a recordset from an external database, manipulates it in UI, then commits the edits back to the database.

Below is a typescript code snippet of the data table component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'employee_table',
template: `
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=6>Name</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Suggested Total Pay</th>
                <th>Total Pay Override</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="#ee of ee_data" [className]=ee.tr_classes [class.selected]="ee.is_selected">
                <td *ngFor="#x of ee.mgmt_spacer"></td>
                <td [attr.colspan]="[6-ee.mgmt_tier]">{{ee.name}}</td>
                <td>{{ee.level}}</td>
                <td>{{ee.rating}}</td>
                <td>{{ee.suggested_tct | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-2'}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="e.g. $100,000"></td>
                <td><textarea rows="1" placeholder="Explain Override" autoGrow ></textarea></td> 
                <td class="txt_btn dr_toggle_btn"
                        (click)="drToggle($event)">{{ee.show_direct && '-' || '+'}}</td>
                <td class="txt_btn desc_toggle_btn">{{ee.show_descendants && '--' || '++'}}</td>
            </tr>
        <table>
        <span class="table_return">Back to Top</span>
            `,
    providers: [EmployeeTableService],
    directives: [AutoGrowDirective]
})
export class EmployeeTableComponent{
    title: string = "Employee Data";
    ee_data;

    constructor(employeeTableService: EmployeeTableService){
        this.ee_data = employeeTableService.getData();
    }

    drToggle(event){
        alert('HEY! '+event.target+'; '+event.target.value);
    }

}
```

I'm struggling with how to use the event listener defined in the template to pass a handle for the javascript object to `drToggle()`.

I would like to expose the underlying javascript array (the recordset `ee_data`) to a processing function that edits that recordset, leaving angular to automatically update the html.

However, it seems that all I can do is pass the $event keyword.  I could conceivably interrogate `$event.target` to get the parent `<tr>`, then look in the html values of its `<td>` elements to find enough info to locate the corresponding record in the javascript object, but this seems very roundabout.

In the ts template, there is a iterative variable `#ee` that is used to build out the html table from the javascript array.  Is there any way I can pass this same `#ee` variable to my event listener directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let ee of ee_data"
...
(click)="drToggle(ee)"
```

You can just pass the iteration variable `ee`

The syntax to declare a variable in `*ngFor` is `let` instead of `#` since several months already.

Comment: Wow.  I don't know why I couldn't get that to work the first time.  It really is that simple.  Thanks!!